# SAS Code for summing lines between dates

Tags: sas, intervals

So I have data which goes something like this

```
 obs | date_of_service | units | CPT | ID
 -----------------------------------------
  1. |   11/03/2015    |   40  |xxxx6| 234
  2. |   11/04/2015    |    1  |xxxx5| 234
  3. |   11/11/2015    |    1  |xxxx5| 234
  4. |   11/18/2015    |    1  |xxxx5| 234
  5. |   11/20/2015    |   40  |xxxx6| 234
  6. |   11/25/2015    |    1  |xxxx5| 234
  7. |   12/02/2015    |    1  |xxxx5| 234
  etc....
```

over many intervals for many Ids,
what I need to do is sum the units for obs between the CPT xxxx6  for each interval since it is a very large dataset with many unique IDs.

ok so this is what I have now:

```
%MACRO lags();
   %let n=1;
   data out;
      set in;
      by id  Date_of_service ;
      DO _n_=&n. until (last.id);
         if (id=lag&n.(id) and CPT="xxxx6") then do;
            if units ne . then output;
            call missing (TOTAL);
         end;
         if CPT="xxxx5" or CPT= "xxxx7" then TOTAL + count;
      END;
   run;
%MEND;
%lags
```

the problem is if I have two or more xxxx6 in a row without a xxxx5 or xxxx7 in between I get a null (.) value or a 0 in TOTAL column. and I'm not getting the first observation line for all of the ids with the xxxx6 cpt.

Comment: And what code have you tried?

Comment: And what do you want your output to look like?

Comment: I've tried doing two macro loops with lag&n. (date of service) and tagging them with a tag and trying to sum it. I can only imagine this would have been a common issue...

Comment: Output would be grouped by provider id, additional ids.  ultimately but that isn't what I need assistance with its more getting my head around a way to code this... I have thought of an SQL doing a sub query join after tagging the xxxx6 in an ascending count variable, but how I would join them back with a sum of the units for xxxx5 between the intervals of the new count variable of 1-2, 2-3, 3-4 and so one... using the lag macro loops I cannot capture the first occurance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edited answer because I can't figure out how to post a new one:
Looks for CPT="xxx6" and stores variables at that point.  Then goes through the next rows summing units till the next xxx6 is reached and outputs before repeating.  This will cause issues if no xxx6 is reached for the last set of observations.  Also, what happens if the ID changes from 234 to 235 mid unit count?  In the solution it would take 234 as the ID to sum.

```
data In;
infile cards;
input OBS DATE_OF_SERVICE:mmddyy10. UNITS CPT:$5. ID;
format DATE_OF_SERVICE date9.;
cards;
1 11/03/2015 40 xxxx6 234
2 11/04/2015 1 xxxx5 234
3 11/11/2015 1 xxxx5 234
4 11/18/2015 1 xxxx5 234
5 11/20/2015 41 xxxx6 234
6 11/25/2015 1 xxxx5 234
7 11/25/2015 1 xxxx5 234
8 11/25/2015 45 xxxx6 234
;
run;

data OUT(drop=ID UNITS DATE_OF_SERVICE OBS
rename=(STORE_UNITS=UNITS STORE_ID=ID STORE_DATE=DATE_OF_SERVICE STORE_OBS=OBS));
set IN;
retain STORE_OBS STORE_DATE STORE_UNITS STORE_ID;
if CPT="xxxx6" then do;
    if STORE_UNITS ne . then output;
    call missing (TOTAL);

    STORE_UNITS=UNITS;
    STORE_DATE=DATE_OF_SERVICE;
    STORE_ID=ID;
    STORE_OBS=OBS;
end;
if CPT="xxxx5" then TOTAL+UNITS;
run;

proc print; run;
```

Comment: I'll give it a go on my data. Thank you.

Comment: I need the sum of the units for CPT "xxxx5" between the lines with CPT "xxxx6" for each interval separately tallied. ie in the first set the sum of the units would be 3 in the second it would be at least 1 (since I stopped but assume its a repeated series without a standard number of observations in each interval).

Comment: so these summary values can be placed on the same line as the preceding observation (ie the sum of obs 2,3,4 would be placed as a new value on obs 1 and the sum of obs 6,7,8 ect would be placed on obs 5 and so on) I hope this helps clarify.  Thanks for all of the help and suggestions!

Comment: what your code does is similar to what a proc freq which gives me the cumulative frequency of the units

Comment: I'll add the code to a loop with the id= lag&n(ID) indicating that the ID must equal prior value else end. Thanks I'll give this a go.

Comment: Perfect, I modified it with the lag loop to do it only for those ids that are applicable. I did have to program to delete those when a xxxx5m came before a xxxx6 and teh xxxx6 which had no xxxx5 after it, but it gave me exactly what i needed to start with and frame the specifics of my code around!!! Thanks!!

Comment: I've updated my code and posted it if you could help me figure out these last two issues I'd appreciate it.

Comment: The first question was answered correctly so a correct answer would be nice in the mean time but:  
1) The code you've now posted doesn't work using the input I've posted (what count is Total+count?)
2) A macro is not not necessary to run the code you've posted  
3) You're going to have to post more input data with corresponding output you're looking for as I can't even begin to guess what you mean

Comment: count is just a counter variable of 1 for each line in the data. the data I'm using is around 200k lines with many different id for which I'm summing the data I use the macro to stop the lag from picking a date of service from a previous loop through the data

Comment: /*lag&n.(Clm_Service_Date) < Clm_Service_Date */

Comment: the output created by your code is a great output I'm just getting counts for phantom "units" when there are two sequential xxxx6 lines without a xxxx5 line between, so in that regard your code breaks down. is there a way to adjust for this. It's definitely better than what I had been trying and a whole lot more condensed sorry for the check mark.

Comment: You're going to have to post more input and the output you'd be expecting from that.  I'm sure this misunderstanding could have been avoided if you'd done that :)

Comment: Having an emoticon at the end of a snarky comment doesn't make it any less pugnacious, nevertheless the information is what it is and a lack of seeing potential errors lies with neither party as there are aberrations and the unforeseen in any method which is why we run these tests on numerous data sets and deal with those unforeseen issues. Thank you for the good start at any rate. :)

Comment: It wasn't snarky at all.  I would like to help hence me trying to decipher the rest of the answers you've given despite not responding to my original request for more information.